# Change font size and color of captions

Tags: captions

With the code below I'm trying to change the font, size, and color of the text of captions.

```
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
    \definecolor[named]{myColorMainB}{RGB}{174,49,54}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={color=myColorMainB,bf}]{caption}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textcolor{myColorMainB}{\sffamily\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{\textcolor{myColorMainB}{\sffamily Figure}}
```

I would like to have all the text (font and labelfont) with the font sffamily with a smaller size than the one produced. Moreover the labelfont (Figure 1.1) should be bold and with the color defined in myColorMainB.

However this is what I get as output
[image]
Moreover, whatever command I insert in the "font=" option fail to change the size of the text.

Can you tell me how to change the color of the label text and the colon, the font of the main text, and the font size?

Comment: I can't replicate your output. This is what I get: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reNhl.png); with [this input/MWE](https://pastebin.com/raw/HjARDJZE). Can you update your post to show a minimal working example that replicates your current setup?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post your code in a compilable format, i.e., `\documentclass{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting a MWE. My preamble is currently 400 lines long. I'm trying to produce a minimal version of it that still contain the bug and I'll post it.

Comment: I've found the bu. For some reasons I have to add "sf" after "bf" in the labelfont definition. This code (`\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={color=myColorMainB,bf,sf},format=plain]{caption}`) works fine but I ignore what "sf" adds